# VBA Error Handling in QueryTables Loop

Tags: vba, excel, csv, error-handling

I am importing multiple csv files from Google Finance and saving the data to a single worksheet. Whenever a URL is not valid I would like it to go to an error handler where it essentially says "this info could not be found" and then continue back to grab the next csv file from the web.

The code works fine UNTIL it gets to an invalid url, and executes the error handler. The error handler does its job the first time, but then when the loop continues with a new URL, it errors again even when the url is valid.

Once the querytable .Refresh errors once, each url after will also error even if it is a valid url. Is there a way to clear the error and move on to the next URL?

```
Code:

Sub getQuotes()

For i = 1 To 3775
    sym = Worksheets("2").Range("C" & i)
    lookup = "TEXT;http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=" + sym + "&startdate=Jun+1%2C+2016&enddate=Aug+5%2C+2016&num=30&authuser=1&output=csv"
    With Worksheets("Raw Data").QueryTables.Add(Connection:=lookup, Destination:=Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A2"))
        .Name = _
        " "
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 775
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
        .TextFileDecimalSeparator = ","
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        On Error GoTo Err1:
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True
    End With
Next

Err1:
Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A:F").EntireColumn.Insert
Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A2") = sym + " data could not be extracted"
Resume Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm seeing the same thing with a slightly different error message. It works fine with a good URL and once it gets a bad one QueryTables.Add keeps giving the same error, "Microsoft Excel Cannot Access the file <URL>", with an error code 1004. The only thing that fixes it is restarting Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Although I was not able to reproduce the specific problem you've referenced, you're missing `Exit Sub` before your Error handling section.  Without it, the code under `Err1:` gets executed after your `For` loop finishes, regardless of whether there was an error.

Simply add `Exit Sub` on the line above your `Err1:` and let 'er rip.  My code worked with an error in the middle of my `sym` list with this change.

Comment: After adding exit sub above Err1:, I still seem to be getting the same issue. For example if in the first iteration "sym" was equal to AAPL, the code will run fine, then if the second iteration "sym" is 3938, it errors because that produces an invalid url (no csv file at that url). Then on the third iteration, say "sym" is TSLA, and it goes to the error handler even though the url generated with that is valid.

Comment: Ah, ok.  3938 is an integer rather than a string which is giving you a problem.  Change `sym` to `cstr(sym)` in your code.  Like so:
`Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A2") = CStr(sym) + " data could not be extracted"`

Comment: My run through worked because I was only passing symbols like xyz that just don't exist.  I didn't pass it any other values with different types.

Comment: What version of Excel are you on? I am using 2007. Using Cstr() for non text is still not working for me. I tried also to use a "sym" that isn't numbers, like a random group of letters and it is still jumping to the error handler for the next valid sym. For example my sym list is AAPL, GGHJ, and TSLA...it is going to the error handler for TSLA

Comment: That's odd, that's not the behavior I'm seeing.  Try adding a break point and stepping through the program with the debugger.

See "Breakpoints" and "Stepping Through Code" in this article.  Open the locals window under View, too, to keep track of variables.
http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=349:excel-vba-debugging-tools-in-visual-basic-editor-breakpoints-break-mode-stepping-through-code-debugging-views&catid=79&Itemid=475

Comment: Strange...I have tried stepping through to make sure all variables are what they should be and all looks good. I have posted the question here (http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?833553-VBA-Error-Handling-in-QueryTables-Loop) and seems others are having the same issue I am. I'm not sure why it would be working fine on your side and not mine...